# Improving performance of Join in Query

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, query-performance

I have a sql (below) where we have to compare some fields in the main table with the existing date dimension table and filter the records which have the `purchase_date` as same as the last day of previous month.

So the idea was to attach the required `date` from the `date-dim` to every record of the joining set containing the `purchase_date` and then compare both these dates and filter. Hence, I did a `cross-join` to achieve this.

Option 1:

```
create temporary view date_dim_sub as
select
    dt,
    fst_day_of_mth,
    lst_day_of_mth
from date_dim_tbl
where dt = add_months(${input_date}, -1);

create temporary view cust_main as
select
    c.cust_nm,
    c.cust_id,
    c.purch_date
from customer c
cross join date_dim_sub d
where c.purch_date = d.lst_day_of_mth;
```

However, when I try to run the above sqls it takes an unusually long time to execute and often gets hanged, forcing us to kill the process.

I thought of using a sub-query (as below) for the `date_dim`, but I read somewhere that sub-queries are not recommended because sub-queries get evaluated for each row in the outer result-set resulting in performance degradation.

Option 2 (using subquery):

```
create temporary view cust_main as
select
    c.cust_nm,
    c.cust_id,
    c.purch_date
from customer c
where c.purch_date <> (select lst_day_of_mth from date_dim_sub where dt = add_months(${input_date}, -1));
```

Is there any way we can rewrite the queries which would ameliorate performance and alleviate any possibility of query getting hanged ? We are using Spark-SQL. There is approx `10M` records in the main table.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "So the idea was to attach the required date from the date-dim to every record of the joining set containing the purchase_date and then compare both these dates and filter", you're describing a regular `JOIN`. Why wouldn't you just do `from customer c join date_dim_sub d on c.purch_date = d.lst_day_of_mth`? Also, since you're using a non-materialized view in option 1, there's not really a practical difference between your two options; option 1 still needs to evaluate that view for each record (or, if it's using the worst case with that cross join, for EVERY record).

Comment: Lets step back. You've given sample of what you are doing, but now lets ask and edit your post.  What do you really want...  A list of ALL customers regardless of a purchase, but if there WAS a purchase, when was the last date based on date EQUAL to same day last month?  Or... All customers who HAD a purchase on/after given date of last month.  You are looking for a single day of activity and who bought?  If you have 25k customers and only 752 purchased on exact day last month? Is that what you want?  Please edit and clarify your original post.